# Apache Flink Kafka Integration Partition Seperation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I  need to implement below data flow. I have one kafka topic which has 9 partitions. I can read this topic with 9 parallelism level. I have also 3 node Flink cluster. Each of nodes of this cluster has 24 task slot.

First of all, I want to spread my kafka like, each server has 3 partition like below. Order is not matter, I  only transform kafka message and send it DB.

Second thing is, I want to increase my parallelism degree while saving NoSQL DB. If I increase my parallelism 48, since sending DB is IO operation, it does not consume CPU, I want to be sure, When Flink rebalance my message, my message will stay in the same server.

Is there any advice for me?

[image: Sample Flow]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spread you Kafka readers across all 3 nodes, I would recommend to start them with 3 slots each and set the parallelism of the Kafka source to 9.

The problem is that at the moment it is not possible to control how tasks are placed if there are more slots available than the required parallelism. This means if you have fewer sources than slots, then it might happen that all sources will be deployed to one machine, leaving the other machines empty (source-wise).

Being able to spread out tasks across all available machines is a feature which the community is currently working on.